# JQuery Queue issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-queue

I am having some serious issues making the JQuery queue work. All the defined functions execute at once, so the class change occurs before the animation- we want it to fade out, then change class, THEN fade back in.

```
function animatePlusMinus(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("ui-icon-minus")) {
        $(this).queue("goPlus",function(next) {
                $(this).fadeOut(500);
                next();
            })
            .queue("goPlus", function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-minus").addClass("ui-icon-plus").fadeIn(500);
            })
            .dequeue("goPlus");

    } else if ($(this).hasClass("ui-icon-plus")) {
        $(this)
            .queue("goMinus", function (next) {
                $(this).fadeOut(500);
                next();
            })
            .queue("goMinus", function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-plus").addClass("ui-icon-minus").fadeIn(500);
            })
            .dequeue("goMinus");
    }
}
```

I could do this simple example with the callback function on `fadeOut`, however I'd like to expand this logic in a way which would need a proper queue. I also need to learn how to use `.queue()`!

**UPDATE**: [Here is an JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zm95ey8u/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're calling `next` immediately after having *started* the fading.

A solution is to pass `next` as callback to `fadeOut`:

```
function animatePlusMinus(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("ui-icon-minus")) {
        $(this).queue("goPlus",function(next) {
                $(this).fadeOut(500, next);
            })
            .queue("goPlus", function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-minus").addClass("ui-icon-plus").fadeIn(500);
            })
            .dequeue("goPlus");

    } else if ($(this).hasClass("ui-icon-plus")) {
        $(this)
            .queue("goMinus", function (next) {
                $(this).fadeOut(500, next);
            })
            .queue("goMinus", function (next) {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-plus").addClass("ui-icon-minus").fadeIn(500);
            })
            .dequeue("goMinus");
    }
}
```

But if you're looking in a more generic solution, you'd probably better dive into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) rather than into queues. Here, with jQuery's implementation of promises, you could do

```
function animatePlusMinus(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("ui-icon-minus")) {
        $(this).fadeOut(500).promise().then(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-minus").addClass("ui-icon-plus").fadeIn(500);
        });
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("ui-icon-plus")) {
        $(this).fadeOut(500).promise().then(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("ui-icon-plus").addClass("ui-icon-minus").fadeIn(500);          
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Without`dequeue` the queue doesn't start at all though. Without `next`, it doesn't move to the next function.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something silly. The promises interface looks promising* for the future but it seems like support isn't wide enough on browsers yet

*(heh)

Comment: @Jess Right now I don't recommend using promises in the browser (I use it a lot on node/io.js) but using jQuery promises when available (for example here or on ajax queries) is a step in the right direction and immediately makes your code cleaner.

Comment: @Jess: FYI jQuery promises work on all browsers that jQuery works on (which is pretty much everything). Using queues is a lot messier as `dystroy` shows

Comment: I assume JQuery has it's own mechanism then? Native javascript promises aren't well supported yet from what I can see

Comment: When you do `$(this).fadeOut(500).promise()` you're getting a jQuery promise, not a native one. That's what I meant with *"jQuery's implementation of promises"* in my answer.